# Count the length of list

Tags: python, count

How can I count the length of list. I have following file

[0 1 2]

[0 1 2]

[0]

[0 1 2]

[0 1 2]

[0]

In above example the first list should print 3 and so on

Comment: So how to parse json file to get the titles?

Comment: So, show us what you've tried!

Comment: Er.. `import json`, `json.loads(raw_data)` where `raw_data` is a string containing all that?

Comment: yes i load the data and then what i have to do in order to parse the titles and connectoirs?

Comment: What is the structure of your data, or do you expect everyone to figure it out?

Comment: I just want to parse in python so that i retrieve all resourceId and titles in .json file

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your entire JSON string is in proper format (e.g. I didn't check it all since it's pretty long) you can load it like this:

```
import json
json_data=open('json_data')

data = json.load(json_data)
print(data)
json_data.close()
```

And then to reference different parts of the JSON like so:

```
data["resouceId"]
data["properties"]["title"]
# etc...
```

## Edit

If you want to get all the `resourceId` then you can try something like:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    if key == "resourceId":
        print(value)
```

Comment: It returns only First resource Id and it would not return titles